# How to convert SUBSELECT with TOP and ORDER BY to JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a working sql select, which looks like this

[Edited: Im sorry i did one mistake in the question, i edited alias of Table1 but im trying the answers]

```
SELECT 
m.Column1
,t2.Column2
,COALESCE
    (
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 Vat
            FROM LinkedDBServer.DatabaseName.dbo.TableName t3 
            WHERE 
                m.MaterialNumber = t3.MaterialNumber COLLATE Czech_CI_AS
                and t3.Currency = …
                and ...
            ORDER BY [Date] DESC
        ), m.Vat
    ) as Vat
FROM Table1 m
JOIN Table2 t2 on (m.Column1 = t2.Column1)
```

It works but the problem is that it takes too long and LinkedServer cut my connection because it takes more than 10 minutes. The purpose of the query is to get newer data from a different database if it exists (i get newest data by top and ordering it by date and precondition is that every data in that database is newer than in mine, thats why im using COALESCE).

But my though is if I was able to rewrite it to JOIN it could be faster. But another problem could be I dont have an primary key (and cant change that).

How can I speed that query up ? (Im using SQL Server 2008 R2) 
Thank you

Here i attached Estimated Query Plan: (Its readable in browser ZOOM :) Estimation is for 2 Coalesce columns.
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the *query execution plan*?

Comment: Indeed check the plan, as SQL Server is relatively smart and it can unbuffle even dependent subqueries in many cases. However I still think it's a fair question/task - to transform/write SQL into RA-friendly JOINs. (The JOIN will only be faster in cases when it triggers a better query plan, should such be found; but moving it into joins also allows greater transparency and 'tweaks' and reduces the unbuffling required.)

Comment: thank you for Idea i forget about execution plan, i attached it to the question, it shows several nested same loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting query using `outer apply`

```
SELECT 
t1.Column1
,t2.Column2
,COALESCE(ou.vat, m.Vat) as Vat
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 m on (m.Column1 = t1.Column1)
outer apply
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 Vat
            FROM LinkedDBServer.DatabaseName.dbo.TableName t3 
            WHERE 
                m.MaterialNumber = t3.MaterialNumber COLLATE Czech_CI_AS
                and t3.Currency = …
                and ...
            ORDER BY [Date] DESC
        ) ou
```

Comment: wow it works, thank you so much. according to estimated plan its 2 times faster (also i got indexing tips). This apply command seems really useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
; WITH vat AS (
  SELECT MaterialNumber COLLATE Czech_CI_AS As MaterialNumber
       , Vat
       , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY MaterialNumber ORDER BY "Date" DESC) As sequence
  FROM   LinkedDBServer.DatabaseName.dbo.TableName
  WHERE  Currency = ...
  AND    ...
)
SELECT t1.Column1
     , m.Column2
     , Coalesce(vat.Vat, m.Vat) As Vat
FROM   Table1 As t1
 INNER
  JOIN Table2 As m
    ON m.Column1 = t1.Column1
 LEFT
  JOIN vat
    ON vat.MaterialNumber = m.MaterialNumber
   AND vat.sequence = 1
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, its little bit complicated than first option but thank you anyway, i will look more deeply into this CTE function.